# UIView autoresizingmask not working for me

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have my app set up so that auto-rotate works. Things like tableviewcontrollers and tabbarcontrollers automatically resize them selves without the need for me to write any code. However I need my webview etc. to resize when the device is turned to landscape. I set:

```
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

but when I rotate the device it does not resize. I am implementing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 16):

I think I finally figured this out.  It seems that the root view of a NIB file does not allow you to specify flexible width and flexible height for the autoresizing mask in interface builder (at least not as of 3.2).  Take a look.  Putting the following code in your `viewDidLoad` seems to fix the problem:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

I did it after the `super` call.

Answer (score 4):

I implement the following in my view controller:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Seems to work well.

Comment: I just tried it there but it doesn't seem to get called when I rotate the simulator. I stuck an NSLOG in there and it's not getting printed.

Comment: Are you putting this in the view controller? Are you overriding other rotation methods, such as `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`?

Comment: I'm using your solution and it works great as long as I rotate the device at least once. If my view is loaded while on portrait it doesn't render resized to the screen's size, until I rotate the device of course. How can I set it up so that it changes the moment the view is loaded?