# MPMoviePlayerController view not resizing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm working with an MPMoviePlayerController which renders its UIView to the right dimensions on landscape, but when rotating to portrait it is simply not resizing. I think it's parent UIView is the one not resizing. How can I set this up?

I followed the instructions that @Alex Reynolds mentions in [UIView autoresizingmask not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988060/uiview-autoresizingmask-not-working-for-me). This showed me that the view does resize when rotated. I still have the problem that when the `UIView` for the `UIViewController` that holds the player is loaded, if the orientation of the device is landscape, they it renders to the right frame, but if the devise is on portrait by the time it is loaded it is not resized to it. With @Alex Reynolds' answer, all I have to do is rotate the device once and it will start resizing properly after that.

It is still bad that it won't resize the first time. Has this happened to anyone before? If so, any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the MPMoviePlayerController's `view`'s autoresizingMask appropriately? Is its superview's `autoresizesSubviews` property set to `YES`? (and likewise, does this superview also resize when rotating? I like to set colourful background colours for my views during testing to verify that they resize correctly when autorotating.)

If it's still not working after checking those properties, you can always set the movie player's view's `frame` property manually. The super view's `layoutSubviews` method is generally the best place to do that, but if it's not a view you've manually subclassed, you can also do it in the view controller.

Comment: I believe I do have the autoresizingMask set up right. I have self.player.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin. I have added more info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self play];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}
-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
//[self.view removeFromSuperview];

_moviePlayer =nil;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
-(void)play
 {

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"stringurlvideo"];
    _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
  // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
      //      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
  //                                             object:_moviePlayer];
   // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFull:)
                                         //        name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
                                         //      object:_moviePlayer];
   // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidExit:)
                                          //       name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                          //     object:_moviePlayer];
    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568)
  {

    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200, 320, 200)];
  }
else
   {
     [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150, 320, 200)];

   }
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    //[_moviePlayer.view setCenter:self.view.center];
    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    }
 - (void) moviePlayBackDidFull:(NSNotification*)notification
    {


    }
 -(void)moviePlayBackDidExit:(NSNotification*)notification 
 {
////[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];




 }
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
 /*   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
   {
      [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200, 320, 200)];
    CGRect rect=[bar frame];
    rect.size.width=self.view.frame.size.width;
    [bar setFrame:rect];

   }
  else
   {

    CGRect rect=[bar frame];
    rect.size.width=480;
    [bar setFrame:rect];
    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, 480, 320-44)];

  }*/

  }
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    if ([player
         respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
     {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
     }
     }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }


  -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
  {
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
   }


 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
 return YES;
  }
  /*- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
 {
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
 }*/
   - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation    duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && toInterfaceOrientation!=UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {

    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568)
    {

    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200, 320, 200)];
    }
    else
    {
        [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150, 320, 200)];

    }
    CGRect rect=[bar frame];
    rect.size.width=self.view.frame.size.width;
    [bar setFrame:rect];
    }
  else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
    CGRect rect=[bar frame];
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568)
    {
    rect.size.width=568;
    }
    else{
        rect.size.width=480;

    }
    [bar setFrame:rect];
    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, rect.size.width, 320-44)];
      }
      }
   - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
      {
  /*  if(fromInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && fromInterfaceOrientation!=UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
      {
      CGRect rect=[bar frame];
    rect.size.width=568;
    [bar setFrame:rect];
    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, 480, 320-44)];
    }
   else
    {
    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200, 320, 200)];
    CGRect rect=[bar frame];
    rect.size.width=self.view.frame.size.width;
    [bar setFrame:rect];
    }*/
   }
    - (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
     {
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation     ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
    CGRect rect=[bar frame];
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568)
    {
        rect.size.width=568;
    }
    else{
        rect.size.width=480;

    }
    [bar setFrame:rect];
    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, rect.size.width, 320-44)];

  }
else if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait && orientation!=UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
   {
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568)
    {
    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200, 320, 200)];
    }
    else
    {
        [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150, 320, 200)];

    }
    CGRect rect=[bar frame];
    rect.size.width=self.view.frame.size.width;
    [bar setFrame:rect];

   }
 }
```